# Can I select or implement a Manipulate bookmark from an arbitrary control?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, gui-construction

I understand how I can select a bookmark from the "+" menu of a `Manipulate`. Is there a way to select a bookmark from an arbitrary control, or define a control that implements bookmark functionality?

For example, if I have something like

```
Manipulate[{x, y, z},
 {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10},
 Bookmarks -> {"Center" :> {x = 5, y = 5, z = 5},"Zero" :> {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}}]
```

Can I add a control that does the same thing as selecting the bookmark from the menu? For example, can I add something similar to `{preset, {"Center", "Zero"}}`, to create something that looks like

[image]

where choosing one of the setters performs assignments to collections of `Manipulate` variables?

Specifically: is there

1. a way to implement bookmark-like functionality by specifying a control that sets several `Manipulate` variables at once; is there
2. a way to explicitly select a bookmark from an arbitrary control (e.g. is there something like an"SelectBookmark[*bookmark*]")?

I'd have thought that

```
Manipulate[{x, y, z}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10},
 {{preset, 
   Which[# === "Center", (x = 5; y = 5; z = 5),
         # === "Zero",   (x = 0; y = 0; z = 0)] &}, {"Center", "Zero"}}]
```

would at least achieve (1), but it has no apparent effect; I see no way to do (2).

Comment: This needs some more thought but the dynamic values of the bookmarks can be displayed: ``Manipulate[Column[{Dynamic@Typeset`bookmarkList,{x, y, z}}],{x, 0, 10},{y, 0, 10},{z, 0, 10},Bookmarks -> (opts = {"Center" :> {x = 5, y = 5, z = 5},"Zero" :> {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}})]`` so the task is how to convert that information into a dynamic setterbar.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi: Yes, that would be relevant to (1). I've extended the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you? (I did this with radio button bar. I like to do this myself with pulldown menu. But the idea is the same)

```
Manipulate[
 {x, y, z},

 (*controls*)
 {x, 0, 10},
 {y, 0, 10},
 {z, 0, 10},

 (*bookmark control*)
 Grid[{
   {Style["bookmarks", Bold],
    RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[bookMark, {bookMark = #;

        Which[
         bookMark == "center", x = 5; y = 5; z = 5,
         bookMark == "zero", x = 0; y = 0; z = 0
         ]

        } &], {"center", "zero"}, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]

    }}, Spacings -> {.5, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.005], Gray]],

 {{bookMark, "zero"}, None}     
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't my approach to (1) work? In particular, I'm confused about the difference between `{{preset {preset = #; Which[preset === "Center", (x = 5; y = 5; z = 5), preset === "Zero", (x = 0; y = 0; z = 0)]} &}` and `Dynamic[bookMark, {bookMark = #; Which[bookMark == "center", x = 5; y = 5; z = 5, bookMark == "zero", x = 0; y = 0; z = 0]} &], {"center", "zero"}]`.

Comment: I've [*suggested* an edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/3918) to a form that parallels the form in the question, to focus on this aspect. I'd have thought that the approach I tried to do (1) in the question would have had the same effect, since the documentation for Manipulate says: "In the form {u,func}, Dynamic[u] is given as the first argument to func."; but there's something about either `Manipulate` or `Dynamic` I'm not grasping here.

Comment: What happens when you add another bookmark after clicking "+"? I assumed what he was after was something that dynamically reads stored bookmarks?